# Bash script to compare two files and display the count of duplicates saved in another file include ip?

Tags: bash, git-bash

I'd like to compare file 1 and file 2 using their first columns and four columns the entire line or row from file 2 where they match in file 1 .I'd also like to save the results in a 3rd file, and count the duplicates.

**File1:**

```
00:00:00 W1 T Y8.4.237 51934 X1.69 51934 17.203.73.207 #S  
00:00:00 W1 U Y8.1.161 63675 W121 63675 200.47.95.8 10]  
00:00:00 W1 T Y8.42.69 35684 X1.71 35684 2.250.5.106 #S  
00:00:00 Q2 T Y0.244.246 61631 X4.126 61631 3.211.0.248 #S  
00:00:01 W1 U Y8.1.161 63674 W121 63674 200.47.95.18 22]
```

**File 2:**

```
Y8.4.237  
Y8.1.161  
Y8.42.69   
Y0.244.246   
Y8.1.161
```

And in file3, I want to include the duplicates and count them.

For example, the result is:

```
Y8.4.237 :  Total 0
Y8.1.161:   Total 2 
Y8.42.69:   Total 0
Y0.244.246 :Total 0
```

I use this command but i could not change by dynamically?

```
awk '{print $4}'  file1.txt |grep  -w -c "Y8.1.161"
```

How can I do this? Thank you a lot for your help and efforts

Comment: Why is this tagged `python` if you're doing it in `bash`?

Comment: Why are the the counts `0`?

Comment: because i need it it is duplicate if not duplicate just count if duplicate we have to count it

Comment: But `Y8.4.237` appears 1 time in file1.txt, why is it `Total 0`?

Comment: you are right,but actually i want to recognize the command the result by this way but i can not write the command, the file 1 include more than 1,000,000 records .

Comment: Ugly way to do  using for and grep.  for i in 'cat file2.txt|sort | uniq`;do echo -n "$i Total:" ;grep $i file1.txt | wc -l; done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an associative array from the contents of `file1.txt`. Then increment the counts when reading `file2.txt`.

```
awk 'FNR==NR { c[$1] = 0; next; } # file2.txt
     $4 in c { c[$4]++ } # file1.txt
     END { for (x in c) printf("%s: Total %d\n", x, c[x]) }
' file2.txt file1.txt > result.txt
```

Comment: actually it was not working, every line total equal 0 ,i want file 2 compare file 1
if in the file 1 ,it is duplicate counting or not put 0,thank you for your efforts

Comment: I had the files in the wrong order

Comment: I also had `=` that should be `==`

Comment: Thank you a lot you saved me, you are right i was wrong when i use it in the wrong order... thank you again